# Loosing environment variables in .cproject in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: environment-variables, eclipse-cdt

I have some Yocto recipes running that clean out my source directories before building.  The problem is that I also have an Eclipse CDT project defined in the same source directory that gets deleted when I do the clean.  I modified my scripts so that the .project and .cproject files would get copied to a safe location and then copied back once the build is complete.  Everything appears to get restored satisfactorily except for the environment variables defined in the Project's Build Configurations (right-click Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Environment).  They get lost.

Now, I can see the environment variables defined in the org.eclipse... directory but it appears that they are time stamped somehow and are out of sync with the Project.  How can I get the Project's Build Configurations to restore automatically? (it is a pain to have to redefined these variables everytime I do a clean/build).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  There is a directory called .settings that appears along side the .project and .cproject files that also needs to be saved and then restored.  When this is done the environment variables define under the project are also restored.